# bias-variance tradeoff: Where is the "U" shape on the test set?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ridge-regression

I've generated a matrix of features (n=200; p=200) and a response variable; split the data up into training and test sets; applied ridge regression with varying degrees of regularisation strengths; and finally plotted the MSE of the training and test sets:
[image]

I am confused as to why I'm not seeing a "U" shape on the test error as alpha varies? I.e. why doesn't the error increase again ("underfit") as the model becomes more and more simple (towards the right). What does this tell me about my data, **and how can I change the way the data are generated with the [make_regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html) function (for which I am not sure I fully understand its documentation) to see the "U"?** Python code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y, w = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=200, coef=True,
                          random_state=1, bias=0, noise=8, tail_strength=0.9, effective_rank=10)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=2)

alphas = 10.**np.arange(-4, 10, 0.1)

scores_test = []
scores_train = []
for a in alphas:
    print(a)
    clf = Ridge(alpha=a, solver='auto')
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    scores_train.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, clf.predict(X_train)))
    scores_test.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(alphas, scores_test, 'r', label='test')
ax.plot(alphas, scores_train, 'b', label='train')
ax.set_ylabel('MSE', fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('alpha (regularisation strength)', fontsize=16)
ax.legend(fontsize=18)
plt.savefig('bias_variance_tradeoff.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a U-shape, it's just difficult to see because it's small. We can make it larger by bumping up the sample size to 1000 and reducing the noise to 3 so that the regression problem is more tractable. This is the plot I got from running your code with those parameters:

[image]

(the fact that the test error is lower than the train error as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ seems to be an artifact of this particular random seed).